# Spark-Submit through command line does not enforce UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, apache-spark, encoding, utf-8, bigdata

When I run my spark job from an IDE using Spark's Java APIs, I get the output in a desired encoding format (UTF-8). But if I start the 'spark-submit' method from command line, the output misses out on the encoding.

Is there a way where I can enforce encoding to 'spark-submit' when used through command line interface.

I am using Windows 10 OS and Eclipse IDE.

Your help will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run your Spark job like this :
 `spark-submit --class com.something.class --name "someName" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=utf-8"`

Answer (score 0):

Not working in my case

The command i use is

```
spark-submit --class com.rera.esearch --jars /Users/nitinthakur/.ivy2/cache/mysql/mysql-connector-java/jars/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar /Users/nitinthakur/IdeaProjects/Rera2/target/scala-2.11/rera2_2.11-0.1.jar
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=utf-8" 127.0.0.1 root
```

Output of below commands

```
println(System.getProperty("file.encoding")) // US-ASCII
println(scala.util.Properties.encodingString) // US-ASCII
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing the issue in a code that runs in executor(like the code between foreachPartition or mapPartition) you would have to set spark.executor.extraJavaOptions that is

```
--conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
```

if your code is running in driver then set as said above, i.e

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=utf-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the arguments order matters. You have to specify the encoding before the JAR file like so:

```
spark-submit --class my.package.app --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=utf-8" --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 my-app.jar
```

I tried specifying the encoding after the JAR file and it seems like the specified encoding doesn't get picked up.